# How to write to HBase in Azure Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, azure-hdinsight, azure-databricks

I'm trying a build a lambda architecture using 'kafka-spark-hbase'. I'm using azure cloud and the components are on following platforms
1. Kafka (0.10) -HDinsights 
2. Spark (2.4.3)- Databricks
3. Hbase (1.2)- HDinsights

All the 3 components are under the same V-net so there is no issue in connectivity.
I'm using spark structured streaming, and successfully able to connect to Kafka as a source.

Now as spark does not provide native support to connect to Hbase, I'm using 'Spark Hortonworks Connector' to write data to Hbase, and I have implemented the code to write a batch to hbase in "foreachbatch" api provided in spark 2.4 onward.

The code is as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

//code dependencies
import com.JEM.conf.HbaseTableConf
import com.JEM.constant.HbaseConstant

//'Spark hortonworks connector' dependency
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase._



    //---------Variables--------------//
    val kafkaBroker = "valid kafka broker"
    val topic = "valid kafka topic"
    val kafkaCheckpointLocation = "/checkpointDir"

 //---------code--------------//
    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

    val kafkaIpStream = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBroker)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .option("checkpointLocation", kafkaCheckpointLocation)
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .load()

    val streamToBeSentToHbase = kafkaIpStream.selectExpr("cast (key as String)", "cast (value as String)")
      .withColumn("ts", split($"key", "/")(1))
      .selectExpr("key as rowkey", "ts", "value as val")
      .writeStream
      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("30 seconds"))
      .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
        batchDF
          .write
          .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> HbaseTableConf.getRawtableConf(HbaseConstant.hbaseRawTable), HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"))
          .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").save
      }.start()
```

Form the logs I can see that code is successfully able to get the data but when it tries to write to Hbase I get the following exception.

```
19/10/09 12:42:48 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 1a54283d-ab8a-4bf4-af65-63becc166328, runId = 670f90de-8ca5-41d7-91a9-e8d36dfeef66] terminated with error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/NamespaceNotFoundException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.DefaultSource.createRelation(HBaseRelation.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:292)
    at com.JEM.Importer.StreamingHbaseImporter$.$anonfun$main$1(StreamingHbaseImporter.scala:57)
    at com.JEM.Importer.StreamingHbaseImporter$.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(StreamingHbaseImporter.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:568)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:566)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:208)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NamespaceNotFoundException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 44 more
19/10/09 12:42:48 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/10/09 12:42:48 INFO AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@42f85fa4{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{172.20.170.72:47611}
19/10/09 12:42:48 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://172.20.170.72:47611
19/10/09 12:42:48 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
19/10/09 12:42:48 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
19/10/09 12:42:48 INFO SQLAppStatusListener: Execution ID: 1 Total Executor Run Time: 0
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO SQLAppStatusListener: Execution ID: 0 Total Executor Run Time: 0
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /local_disk0/tmp/temporaryReader-79d0f9b8-c380-4141-9ac2-46c257c6c854
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /local_disk0/tmp/temporary-d00d2f73-96e3-4a18-9d5c-a9ff76a871bb
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /local_disk0/tmp/spark-b92c0171-286b-4863-9fac-16f4ac379da8
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /local_disk0/tmp/spark-ef92ca6b-2e7d-4917-b407-4426ad088cee
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /local_disk0/spark-9b138379-fa3a-49db-95dc-436cd7040a95
19/10/09 12:42:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /local_disk0/tmp/spark-2666c4ff-30a2-4161-868e-137af5fa3787
```

What all have I tried:

There are 3 ways to run spark jobs in databricks:

1. Notebook: I have Installed SHC jar as library on the cluster and placed 'hbase-site.xml' into my job jar and installed it onto the cluster as well, not I have pasted the main class code onto the notebook, When I run it I'm able to load dependencies from SHC but get above error.
2. Jar: This is almost similar to notebook, with that difference that instead of notebook, I give the main class and the jar to the job and run it. Gives me the same error.
3. Spark submit: I created an uber-jar with all the dependencies including SHC, I uploaded the hbase-site file to dbfs path and provided above in the submit command as below.

```
[
"--class","com.JEM.Importer.StreamingHbaseImporter","dbfs:/FileStore/JarPath/jarfile.jar",
"--packages","com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11",
"--repositories","http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/",
"--files","dbfs:/PathToSiteFile/hbase_site.xml"
]
```

Still I get the same error. Can anyone please help?
Thanks

Comment: I've got no idea what might be wrong, but I'd try to run the app outside Databricks to see if that could cause it. Did you try to run the app using the good ol' `spark-submit`?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, yup I tried running the app on Spark HDinsights with spark submit, with the same parameters as above, it works fine. The only difference being that on HDinsights cluster I have replicated the 'hbase-site.xml' on every node, so I'm sure spark has access to it, here as vm's spawn up on the run I'm not sure that is happening, but as specified in '3' I'm mentioning '--files' option, so spark should have access to it no matter which vm the executor is running on.

Comment: That seems more an issue of [azure-databricks] not Spark itself, doesn't it? You should find a way to configure a notebook with the necessary jars (and possibly override whatever are the defaults).

Comment: BTW Did you try to write to HBase as a batch query in Spark SQL alone? That would exclude Spark Structured Streaming from the mix as a possible cause.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, yes I tried writing a batch query as well, I get the same error. Yes I also think this is specific to databrick and I have 2 speculations
1. It is not getting hbase-site.xml
2. It is not able to load the connector.

for both of which I tried creating a fat jar and providing --files option, still it didn't work.

Comment: Can you look at the web UI's Environment and see if you can find anything helpful? That's likely your last resort before delving deeper into Databricks platform itself.

Comment: I have reached near the problem, the basic problem was SHC requires hbase supporting jars to write data to hbase, these jars were missing, 'https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/issues/223#issuecomment-375111619' this link helped me get closer to the issue.

Comment: But now I'm getting another exception:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(Lorg/json4s/JsonInput;Z)Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;`

This also seems to be a dependency issue, this is what I have tried

1. Uploaded the following jars: json4s-ast, json4s-core,json4s-jackson
2. Versions tried, 3.4,3.5,3.6
3. Put a maven dependency in my jar, built fat jar and uploaded it as library, so transitive dependencies can be satisfied.

The easiest way to solve this problem would be to mention --packages,--repositories, as mentioned in the question its not working

Comment: The last I tried to use SHC was just tons of mess. See [Dataproc Bigtable Spark-HBase Connector Example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/scala/bigtable-shc). In the end, I was told to migrate to the other HBase connector at https://github.com/apache/hbase-connectors. Looks like [1.0.0](https://github.com/apache/hbase-connectors/releases) is available!

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I tried using his connector, but this connector uses hbase 2.X dependencies while my server is 1.1.2.2.6.3.84-1, and due to this I ran into issue which is specified here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-19145